# Simple slider - CSS background-image vs <img> for srcset-like responsive behaviour & accesibility?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, semantic-markup

I know that the topic of `<img />` vs `background-image()` is extensively covered, but there is one aspect of it that I have doubts about.

I have a full-size slider on my page. It showcases high-resolution images in the background, but they are not part of semantic content, merely design. I want to keep the images crisp, yet not to congest traffic.

I love the `srcset` feature, and it would be a great tool for this job, but that would require me to use an `<img />` tag or similar. On the other hand, I could stick with CSS' `background-image()` and use a `@media` workaround (sadly, `image-set()` isn't standard yet). (I'd like to avoid Javascript for this case).

Both solutions have their disadvantages. **How would each of them weigh on the accesibility & semantic aspects?**

One of the goals of this project is to keep the mark-up as lean and structured as possible. So, something like:

```
<h1>Welcome to Thiswebsite!</h1>
<p>We do lots of exciting stuff here.</p>
<ul class="slider">
    <li>
        <h2>Travel & Lifestyle</h2>
        <p>This is slide 1. Lorem ipsum text and into. <a href="link">Find out more.</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Sodomy</h2>
        <p>This is slide 2. Wait what? Also info and intro. <a href="link">Spank me.</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...is not that bad even when displayed as plain text. Putting images in there would make it awkward to navigate, though. It's a fringe case, but it really makes me think about what the proper way to layout the elements would be.

Please let me know if information provided is inusfficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

CSS is perfectly fine.

You may also chose to use `<img>` tags but as you want them not to be part of semantic content, you will have to define them accordingly.

Using `<img role="presentation" alt="" />` is a perfect choice.

Empty `alt` attribute is sufficient and mandatory for screenreaders to make them ignore the image. Using `role="presentation"` will assert that you willingly wanted them not to be announced by screenreaders (and would avoid any doubt in case of accessibility audit for instance).

Comment: I had no idea about ```role="presentation"```, thank you. As for CSS being fine, do you mean you would use @media queries?

Comment: @DwarfVader That's the standard solution for decorative images. It depends on your implementation, or for example, if you want to have different images on other pages, ...

Comment: Thank you. The only concern I have left is scalability. Let's say I have a slider for each of the main pages. Pages might be added or removed later, or the sliders changed. Would you include them in your ```main.css``` or in an on-demand ```slider-slidername.css```?